# Do something when page reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page, on this page I have a pop up that appears when either you go to that page or you reload the page. Also my page reloads every minutes.

I use this code :

```
if(window.location.href == "http://local.mysite.com:8080/")
{
   setInterval("location.reload(true)", 60000);
};
```

What I'd like to do is when the page is reload the pop up doesn't show.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Think you need to have a look at using cookies or something if I get your question right. (What popup by the way? Where is your HTML code?)

Comment: `Also my page reloads every minutes, ` ..EVERY MINUTE!!!  are you serious ?? what if i am in the middle of the page trying to read something and bang!!! reloads.. again reloads!!!!.. :)

Comment: Does the reload work? You are passing the js a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a parameter in url to detect if page is first time loaded or reloaded, Try this:

```
if (location.href.indexOf("http://local.mysite.com:8080/") === 0) {
    var url = location.href;
    if (url.indexOf('r=1') === -1) {
        console.log('show popup');
        url += url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?r=1' : '&r=1';
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        location.href = url;
    }, 60000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `location.reload(true)` is reloading your page every minute. That should not happen.
Instead you should use `setInterval` on popup or some other element.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you shouldn't be using `setInterval` for this, as the page will be reloaded anyway. A simple `setTimeout` should suffice.

Furthermore, don't use a string as first parameter for these kind of functions, as it will result in JavaScript using `eval`, which can lead to icky stuff regarding globals. Try using a closure: `setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true); }, 60000);`.

Now to address the pop-up problem on page-reloads. You can simply add a parameter to your url like so: `http://local.mysite.com:8080/?reloaded=true`, and read this from JavaScript. This would require you to swap the `location.reload` to something like `location.href = 'http://local.mysite.com:8080/?reloaded=true';.`